# Basic math - normalizing the denominator

Tags: complex-numbers

I don't understand how to get from step 2 to step 3 here:

[image]

Is there some denominator normalization that I'm not getting? Can I use this method whenever I want to move a polynomial in a denominator to the numerator? Working with complex numbers here.

Comment: It is generally true that $\frac 1{1+z}\approx 1-z$ for small $z$.  After all, $(1-z)(1+z)=1-z^2\approx 1$.  You can get more detailed information out of the geometric series $\frac 1{1+z}=1-z+z^2-z^3+\cdots$.

Comment: using [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), $(1+x)^{-1}\approx 1-x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a calculation of the formal inverse of a series
$$
1 + ax + bx^2 + \cdots.
$$
Multiplying out
$$
(1 + ax + bx^2 + \cdots) (1 - ax + ?x^2 + \cdots) 
= 1 + 0x + \text{higher order terms}
$$
shows that the coefficient of $x$ in the formal inverse is $-a$.

To prove convergence or find the rest of the coefficients you have to do the work in each particular case.